# Based on a value of cell data B2, the cells C2:W2 will be set to the number 0 as well

Tags: excel, vba

I have an excel sheet which is filling data from a macro previously made.

I have data from B2 to W2 at X amount of rows.

How would I have a code to Read the value from B2, and if B2 equals 0 the entire row would change to 0's, with the change of the interior row changing to Green? And if B2 is anything other then 0, do nothing. Also is it possible to do this with a loop for X amount of rows?

As in B1,B2,B3...BX

Thank you for any help.

EDIT**
I have tried something similar to this,

RowAmount Defines how many rows there are.

```
For Each cell in Range("B2:B" & RowAmount & "")

    If cell.value = 0 Then
        (part where I am Stuck on to change entire row)
    End If
Next cell
```

This portion does not include the color changing (which I also have problems with)

Comment: `If` statement to check if the value is 0 then... and a `Loop` like `For Each` to loop through all the rows you need.

Comment: Or conditional formatting. What have you tried?

Comment: I have tried something similar to this,

RowAmount Defines how many rows there are.

For Each cell in Range("B2:B" & RowAmount & "")
    If cell.value = 0 Then
        (part where I am Stuck on to change entire row)
    End If
Next cell

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a combination of Range & Cells, where values **2** and **23** are responsible for applying changes to columns B:W for a given Row.

```
For Each cell In Range("B2:B" & rowAmount & "")
    If cell.Value = 0 Then
        Range(Cells(cell.Row, 2), Cells(cell.Row, 23)).Value = 0
        Range(Cells(cell.Row, 2), Cells(cell.Row, 23)).Interior.Color = RGB(0, 200, 0)
    End If
Next cell
```

Hope it works for you.
Also make sure that you properly declare your variables:

```
Dim cell As Range
Dim rowAmount As Long
```

Comment: Thanks Justyna MK! Worked great!

Comment: You're welcome! Feel free to mark my answer as correct. Take care.